# Convert a batch of xlsx to xls in programmatically using python in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

Does anyone know a simple procedure in python to convert a batch of `xlsx` files to `xls` using Python in an Ubuntu environment?

I know of the command-line solution but I want an implementation from within a python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu, you can install `unoconv`

```
sudo apt-get install unoconv
unoconv -f xls test.xlsx
```

If you have multiple files to convert, try:

```
ls *xlsx | xargs unoconv -f xls
```

*Alternatively*, you can wrap up the command by python script:

```
import glob
import os

xlsx_files = glob.glob("*xlsx")
for xlsx_file in xlsx_files:
    os.system("unoconv -f xls {0}".format(xlsx_file) )
```

My OS is Ubuntu 15.10
**Please backup your files and then try the command.**

Comment: This is what I was looking for!! I tried for i   in *.xlsx; do  libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv "$i" ; done but realized it was converting to odt format which was not compatible with what I was converting file for.Thanks you saved my face

Comment: @Joshua glad it helps. can you press the check mark to choose this as the correct answer:)

Comment: Just a note: to avoid matching multiple files with *.xlsx file extensions which might convert unintended files and mess you up you can pass absolute path to glob.glob like glob.glob(/path/to/myxlsxfiles)